# python : Run Model number of times

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I used for loop to run a model number of times, 
the problem I faced when I run code the value still the same for all run times! but in reality each run gives different value

i use SVR from SKlearn ,,,, if i use the same code without for loop and try to run the code for example 5 times , the results value will differ from each other, and i need the for loop do this without use max_iter parameter in SVM

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
Max_iter = 10
for l in range(0,Max_iter):
    SVRGWO = SVR(kernel = 'rbf',gamma=0.032 ,C=16187.696941074802)
    SVRGWO.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_preda = SVRGWO.predict(X_test)

    MAEValue1 = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_preda, multioutput='uniform_average') # it can be raw_values
    print(MAEValue1)
```

Comment: Of course it will give the same result because you run the same code 10 times.

Comment: Why would it be different? Is there a random element in SVR? I couldn't find any in the docs, for example there's no random seed.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using SKLearn's SVR? If so, please state so explicitly in your question.

Comment: yes i use SVR from SKlearn ,,,, if i use the same code without for loop and try to run the code for example 5 times , the results value will differ from each other, and i need the for loop do this without use max_iter parameter in SVM .

Comment: under stand what i say ?

Comment: Yes. Please edit your question to explicitly say what you've said in comments. All the information needed to answer a question should be in the question.

Comment: Also, please add a (minimal) dataset so that we can reproduce the problem. To learn more, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is still a random_state propagated in the libsvm even though it's not present in the parameters of the SVR classe (as you can see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/svm/classes.py#L920))

Try to set the seed before your loop with: `np.random.seed(0)`.